# How to set a microdata image property, without letting the browser download the image?

Tags: html, image, microdata

I have a website on which images are displayed. The images which are displayed are resized and then cached by the web application. But the cache is volatile. For the microdata I want to link to non-volatile images.

My current solution for this is

```
<img src="cache/image-resized.jpg" />
<img src="static/image.jpg" itemprop="image" style="display:none;"/>
```

This works. Google interprets the microdata correctly and the resized image is displayed. But the users browser also downloads the static image, which is a large image.

So how do I set a microdata image property, without letting the browser download the image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>(Note: a now deleted answer suggested the use of the `meta` element)</sub>

Instead of the `meta` element, you [should use the `link` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#the-basic-syntax), because the content is a URI:

> When a string value is a URL, it is expressed using the `a` element and its `href` attribute, the `img` element and its `src` attribute, or other elements that link to or embed external resources.

It’s even [required](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values):

> If a property's value, as defined by the property's definition, is an absolute URL, the property must be specified using a URL property element.

So it should be:

```
<link itemprop="image" href="static/image.jpg" />
```