# Google plus snippet - Image thumbnail is not shown

Tags: google-plus, meta-tags, google-plus-one, schema.org, facebook-opengraph

Testing posting a snippet on Google+ with following HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/le2WbeU.jpg" />   
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://i.imgur.com/le2WbeU.jpg">
</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

What I see is:
[image]

Looking at network traffic I see a failed request: 
[image]

**UPDATE:** Looks like it was a caching problem. Once I appended a query string on to the URL, I got the image to pull up. I must have had a bad URL to an image the first time and it cached that bad URL request.

Comment: It's possible that imgur is blocking Google's direct requests for the image. They did start recently redirecting direct image requests to an HTML page if they were not refered from Twitter/Facebook/etc. Try using some different image hosts.

Comment: Looks like it was a caching problem. Once I appended a query string on to the URL, I got the image to pull up. I must have had a bad URL to an image the first time and it cached that bad URL request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a caching problem. Once I appended a query string on to the URL, I got the image to pull up. I must have had a bad URL to an image the first time and it cached that bad URL request.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it causes the error, but you might want to use `link` instead of `meta` if the value is a URI.

- The HTML5 spec defines that the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element):

  > […] represents various kinds of metadata that cannot be expressed using the […] [`link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) […] elements.
- Microdata [also explicitly requires it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669):

  > […] the property must be specified using a URL property element

Also note that you don’t have created an item in your Microdata, so the `image` property is not defined (unless an item is created on the `html` start tag, which is missing in your example; or you reference it via `itemref` from the `body`).

Comment: Google docs specify using `meta` tags. https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/  Can you clarify what you are referring to by "item in your Microdata" Which item?

Comment: @dev.e.loper: It might work for Google etc., but it’s invalid Microdata. --- Re. item, this is the basic Microdata concept. A Microdata "item" gets created by using the `itemscope` attribute. It represents a thing. This item/thing can have a type (`itemtype`). All descendant properties (`itemprop`) belong to this item. In your small example, you don’t have created an item. Your `image` property doesn’t belong anywhere, it’s also not defined (it’s likely that you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary, but then you’d need to specify that.)