# Schema.org Organizational markup Issue

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I was trying to implement this for my website:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/05/using-schemaorg-markup-for-organization.html

I have a quick doubt on this:

Is it compulsory to tag existing visible on page elements on homepage??
say if we don't have a visible logo image on homepage, Can we add a separate logo image in a piece of code in body section as mentioned like :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" style="display:none;">
 <a itemprop="url" href="http://myDomain.com/"></a>
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://myDomain.com/logo.png" /> </div>
```

So, if i add CSS "display:none" to my DIV and place anywhere on body, Will it be considered by google for Organizational markup??﻿

CSS style "display:none" can be added from CSS file, Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding an element, you could simply use `link` ([for URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669)) or `meta` (for text) elements. They are typically hidden by default. If used for Microdata, [`link` and `meta` are allowed in `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633).

Assuming that you want to visually hide the URL as well as the logo:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
 <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/">
 <link itemprop="logo" href="http://example.com/logo.png">
</div>
```

If this is considered by parsers (like search engines) is up to them. It’s valid HTML + Microdata.

Comment: Actually i didn't wanted to hide, but i don't have any other option. Actually as mentioned earlier i don't have a logo or URL on my homepage which i can tag to schema itemprop. Do i need to add it on every page of my website or just the homepage?? I got thr previous answer of using link and meta tags, but how about the enclosing DIV?

Comment: @user1057641: You don’t *have* to add anything, it all depends on what you want to achieve. If you have data you want to annotate with Microdata, but which shouldn’t be visible on the page, use `link`/`meta`. It makes sense to [use Microdata on every page](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633), but again, this is not "required". -- Parsers (like Google) might consider using your Microdata only when specific properties are used. But discussing this is off-topic on SO (might be on-topic on [webmasters.se]).

Answer (score 1):

This question is more than one year old, but since I found it via Google, I figured it will keep popping up in the future - so here's my update of the existing answers:

You don't need to worry about visible elements anymore, you can simply use this instead:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Organization",
"url": "http://www.example.com/",
"logo": "http://www.example.com/logo.png"
}
</script>
```

As far as my understanding goes, you only need to add this code to the homepage.

(This information was added to the OP's article on 21 October 2014.)