# Using Schema.org’s "url" property on a Product page without adding a visual link

Tags: schema.org, microdata

After a bit of research I found recommendations as in:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <a itemprop="url" href="URLOFPRODUCT">Link</a>
</div>
```

But I am trying to avoid linking to the product, on the product page.

Another approach I've noticed is the use of meta tags but outside the `head`, which is a big 'no no'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For providing a URL in Microdata, you [**must** use "a URL property element"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669). Currently these are:
`a`, `area`, `audio`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `link`, `object`, `source`, `track`, and `video`.

`a` and `link` are the only "generic" elements from this set.

If you don’t want to provide a visual link (by using `a`), go with `link` (which is [typically hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840515/1591669) in browser default stylesheets). This is not "a big 'no no'", as `link` elements are [allowed in the `body` if used for Microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633).

Comment: Can I just ask, for other elements I wouldn't like to show up on the page, like brand name.. is it safe to go for the same approach?

Comment: @ChrisD: If it’s a URL, use `link`. If not (i.e., it is text), use `meta`.