# where should I place the product schema microdata

Tags: html, seo, google-search, schema.org, microdata

I want to improve my product's page for SEO, so I read the information on schema.org but, still got questions. I generated the following microdata from http://schema-creator.org/product.php:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<a itemprop="url" href="www.thisurl.com"><div itemprop="name"><strong>pressure relief valve</strong></div>
</a>
<div itemprop="description">pressure relief valves description</div>
<div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<span itemprop="name">franko</span></div>
<div itemprop="manufacturer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
Manufactured by: <span itemprop="name">franco instrumentation</span></div>
<div>Model: <span itemprop="model">2000</span></div>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">12</span> reviews</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span itemprop="price">$120</span><link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" /> New</div></div>
```

but in my webpage I have the following:

```
<div id="ffc-ProdInfoText">
      <h1 style="color:#A281BE;"> SERIE 1000: Pressure Vacuum Valve</h1>
      <br />
      <h2>For storage tanks used in the Oil and gas Industry</h2>
    </div>
```

So my question is, can I use my current h1 and h2 tags and just add microdata to them? something like this:

```
 <div id="ffc-ProdInfoText" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <a itemprop="url" href="www.thisurl.com"><h1 itemprop="name" style="color:#A281BE;"> SERIE 1000: Pressure Vacuum Valve</h1>
      </a>
      <br />
      <h2 itemprop="description">For storage tanks used in the Oil and gas Industry</h2>
    </div>
```

and... what about  the rest of the info,  can it be hidden? or should I have to add the whole information? 'cause all that data will make me change the design of our webpage, it won't fit as it is

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and should) use your existing markup. Be aware that [some elements come with special rules](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63189/17633).

Yes, you can hide elements containing Microdata. Ideally, you’d use `meta` and `link` elements for this purpose (they are [allowed in the `body` exactly for this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840515/1591669)). You could also omit those properties (neither Microdata nor Schema.org define required properties). Note that some consumers, like search engines, might not consider all hidden markup.