# Hidden Breadcrumbs Rich Snippet

Tags: breadcrumbs, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I want to implement breadcrumbs for my site but I do not want to create any visible tags for that on my page. I thought of using meta tags but as they do not have `href` property, they can’t contain the `itemprop="url"` property. Following is the code I am using:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <meta href="http://www.example.com/dresses" itemprop="url">
    <meta itemprop="title" content="Dresses">

</div>  
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <meta href="http://www.example.com/dresses/real" itemprop="url">
    <meta itemprop="title" content="Real Dresses">
</div>  
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <meta href="http://www.example.com/clothes/dresses/real/green" itemprop="url">
    <meta itemprop="title" content="Real Green Dresses">
</div>
```

Is there any workaround method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 defines that the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)

> […] represents various kinds of metadata that cannot be expressed using the `title`, `base`, `link`, `style`, and `script` elements.

The [`link` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) "allows authors to link their document to other resources".

So you have to use `link` instead of `meta` if the value is a URI. ([Microdata explicitly requires this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669), too.)

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/dresses">
  <meta itemprop="title" content="Dresses">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Terms of Service, every markup up have to be visible to each user.
Don't include any hidden markup because Google will penalize you.

Comment: that's not true, there are exceptions given in google's documentation for machine-readable information. It is a policy, not a terms of service so adherence is not judged as harshly http://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies